# Unable to install NET Framework 4.7.1 on Server Core installation Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-core, dotnet-framework

or "Update is not applicable to your computer" for NET Framework 4.7.1 on Server Core installation Windows Server 2016

Trying to update net framework to 4.7.1 on a Server Core installation but no dice. The installation starts to extract the files for the setup, runs the `setup.exe /x86 /x64 /redis` flashes the .NET logo and shows the license terms windows to continue. Accepts and clicks install and the installation just disappears without further explanation.

The problem exists on another server - identical source and installation. But it works on a identical source and installation but with Desktop Experience.

Looking at the log file...

```
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] === Logging started: 2018/02/25 20:05:03 ===
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] Executable: C:\NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe v4.7.2558.0
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] --- logging level: standard ---
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] Successfully bound to the ClusApi.dll
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] Error 0x800706d9: Failed to open the current cluster
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] Cluster drive map: ''
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] Considering drive: 'C:\'...
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] Drive 'C:\' has been selected as the largest fixed drive
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] Directory 'C:\b2f695ed043f576c934668\' has been selected for file extraction
[2/25/2018, 20:5:3] Extracting files to: C:\b2f695ed043f576c934668\
[2/25/2018, 20:13:3] Extraction took 33.562 seconds
[2/25/2018, 20:13:3] Executing command line: 'C:\b2f695ed043f576c934668\\Setup.exe   /x86 /x64 /redist'
[2/25/2018, 20:13:36] Exiting with result code: 0x0
[2/25/2018, 20:13:36] === Logging stopped: 2018/02/25 20:13:36 ===
```

Looking in the `CBS.log` file. But nothing indicating why the installation doesn't go through.

Copying the extracted files to a new path while the installation package has not stopped - running: `wusa.exe Windows6.1-KB4019990-x64.msu`

**Finally something to work with, it shows:** `The update is not applicable to your computer`

Looking at all requirements from Microsoft doesn't explicit state the Framework 4.7.1 is not supported on Server Core.

So would appreciate all theories or ideas on how to troubleshoot this for a solution ?

---

Windows OS...

```
PS C:\> systeminfo.exe
Host Name:                 SERVERNAME
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
```

Windows features...

```
PS C:\> get-windowsfeature -name *framework* | where-object {$_.Installed -match "True"}
Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[X] .NET Framework 4.6 Features                         NET-Framework-45-Fea...        Installed
    [X] .NET Framework 4.6                              NET-Framework-45-Core          Installed
    [X] ASP.NET 4.6                                     NET-Framework-45-ASPNET        Installed
```

Windows Updates...

```
PS C:\> Get-Hotfix
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
SECDC9SRV101  Update           KB3192137     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  2016-09-12 00:00:00
SECDC9SRV101  Update           KB4049065     SECDC9SRV101\Admi... 2018-02-25 00:00:00
SECDC9SRV101  Update           KB4077525     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  2018-02-25 00:00:00
```

Comment: (as also stated in the not accepted answer) To add to this, the real issue, was that this installation package and its GUI is not compatible with Windows Server Core only with Desktop Experience. But if you tell it to be totally quiet and not use any GUI it will install fine:
NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to install Windows update KB4033393

> On Windows 10 Anniversary Update, Windows 10 Creators Update, and
>   Windows Server 2016 you can find this as Update for Microsoft Windows
>   (KB4033393) under Installed Updates in Control Panel.

which includes .NET Framework 4.7.1 on board.

Another source link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers where you can download offline bundle and install it as it described here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4033342/the-net-framework-4-7-1-offline-installer-for-windows

Comment: Yes, KB4033393 worked nicely. Thanks. The link however redirected back to the original NDP package that I used from the start. But got your specified package from this link instead: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4033393

Answer (score 1):

For Core, make sure you are using `/q` or else the install dialog will fail.  Also, `get-windowsfeature` won't show .Net 4.7 installed.  Not sure what is going on there.

You can run this reg command to see the release of .net

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v Release
```

If it's 70805 (hex) or higher, you are good.

Comment: Dear Drive-By Downloader: Didja notice how Joe didn't come back after your rude, impersonal and cowardly silent clubbing? Can you blame him?